# Using openssl to generate a CSR for an ECC key stored in an HSM - key encode error

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to generate a CSR using openssl 1.1.1l.  This is an ECC key, not an RSA key.

```
$>openssl req -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine -new -key id_464F4F -out ecc_csr.pem -sha256
engine "pkcs11" set.
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [US]:
State or Province Name (full name) [California]:
Locality Name (eg, city) [Campbell]:
Organization Name (eg, company) [NewHorizons]:
Unit Name [DevR_DQA]:
Common Name [www.newhorizons.fluff]:
Email [test@example.com]:
problems making Certificate Request
34359836736:error:0B07807E:x509 certificate routines:X509_PUBKEY_set:public key encode error:crypto/x509/x_pubkey.c:73:

$>
```

The log file for the HSM shows no errors.

So my question becomes, is this an openssl version problem, or am I missing a flag, or maybe a problem in the openssl configuration file?

to be clear, it isn't a problem with the engine configuration, as I can generate RSA CSRs without issue.

The key is in the HSM:

```
CKO_PRIVATE_KEY:

+ 3.1
  CKA_KEY_TYPE                   = CKK_ECDSA
  CKA_SENSITIVE                  = CK_TRUE
  CKA_EXTRACTABLE                = CK_FALSE
  CKA_LABEL                      = FooECC
  CKA_ID                         = 0x464F4F (FOO)
```

Thanks in advance,

r

Comment: OpenSSL [simply calls an 'ameth'](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/x509/x_pubkey.c#L72) (i.e. ASN1-related method) for the key, which for an engine key is supplied by the engine. The engine method apparently returned false without setting any info in the error stack (as OpenSSL code normally should) so yes the engine is where you'll have to look, and the pkcs11 engine is not actually part of OpenSSL. Do you have source? Do you have or can you get a version compiled with symbols to debug?

Comment: this is opensc's pkcs11 engine, so I have the source.  But I'm trying to figure out where the symbol pkey->ameth->pub_encode gets populated.  Digging down into that, I get " if (check_key_fork(key) < 0) return NULL; " and yeah, that rolls right back up via a bunch of return statements.  Deeper than that there is a check for the key and that might be returning null too.  Will debug deeper.